# How to work with Chat View using Alamofire in swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

I am new to ios,I am trying to do chat section.I have API's to integrate..like chat list API,Chat conversation API's (GET & POST).I have integrated chat list API, to show the list of chats.My task is,When i click on one chat in chat list, it has to redirect to chat view screen.I am able to do this.But the problem is,How to differentiate the list of messages for sender and receiver.I designed the chat view screen with XIB'S.If any one helps me to do this would be great.Thank in advance.

```
//GET API Response

{
    "success": 1,
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "conversation": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "chat_id": 4,
                "user_id": 4,
                "type": 0,
                "message": "Hi mahitha",
                "delivered_at": "2019-02-27 14:59:58",
                "read_at": "2019-02-27 15:00:03",
                "created_at": "2019-02-27 12:26:39"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "chat_id": 4,
                "user_id": 4,
                "type": 0,
                "message": "Hello kaveri",
                "delivered_at": null,
                "read_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-27 15:22:11"
            },
            {
                "id": 33,
                "chat_id": 4,
                "user_id": 4,
                "type": 0,
                "message": "125698532",
                "delivered_at": null,
                "read_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-03-05 15:11:38"
            },
            {
                "id": 34,
                "chat_id": 4,
                "user_id": 4,
                "type": 0,
                "message": "1256985322565",
                "delivered_at": null,
                "read_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-03-05 15:16:39"
            }
        ],
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "next_page_url": null
    }
}


//POST API RESPONSE

{
    "success": 1,
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "conversation": {
            "chat_id": 10,
            "user_id": 4,
            "type": "0",
            "message": "123456",
            "created_at": "2019-03-08 12:14:18",
            "id": 55
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here, or please explain more... Thank you.

Comment: "How to differentiate the list of messages for sender and receiver" Your message may contain sender Id . You can compare the sender id with current user id to find which message are sent and which are received

Comment: show us your message data model so one can help you out :)

Comment: Please check the message data above

Answer (score 0):

Posting some code that you have tried will help out more here. But generally this is how you can achieve a chat interface.

Step 1: Create a `tableview` with 2 custom cells. One for Sent message and the other for received message.

Step 2: Design a label for each cell & make sent message right aligned to view with white background color. Make received message left aligned to view with green as background color.

Step 3: Add an addition key in your JSON called `message_type` with either a string `sent` or `received` for each type of message. (This is how you can differ if the message needs to be shown as a sent message or received)

Step 4: Once you navigate from conversations screen to chat screen. Fetch the JSON and add each message to a data model array.

Step 5: Load the data from this array in your `tableview` and use the `message_type` key to either use `sent message custom cell` or `received message custom cell`. This will add all sent messages to the right with white background and all received message to the left with green background.